# Wpf DataGrid only showing empty rows

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

so  i am working on the app which retrieves data from the database and i want to display it in DataGrid with custom columns which i created.

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x: Name = "dataGridAddedAgents" Grid.Column = "0" Grid.ColumnSpan = "7"  ItemsSource = "{Binding}"  HorizontalAlignment = "Stretch" Margin = "10,0" Grid.Row = "3" VerticalAlignment = "Top" AutoGenerateColumns = "False"  IsReadOnly = "True" >
<DataGrid.Columns>            
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding = "{Binding Path=Id}"  Width = "0.25*"  Header = "Id" CanUserResize = "False" CanUserReorder = "False" Foreground = "{x:Null}" />                    
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding = "{Binding Path=FirstName}" Width = "0.15*"  Header = "First name" CanUserResize = "False" CanUserReorder = "False" Foreground = "{x:Null}" />                                         
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding = "{Binding Path=LastName}" Width = "0.15*"  Header = "Last name" CanUserResize = "False" CanUserReorder = "False" Foreground = "{x:Null}" />                                                     
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding = "{Binding Path=Email}"  Width = "0.20*"  Header = "Email" CanUserResize = "False" CanUserReorder = "False" Foreground = "{x:Null}" />                                                               
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding = "{Binding Path=Username}"  Width = "0.15*" Header = "Username" CanUserResize = "False" CanUserReorder = "False" Foreground = "{x:Null}" />                        
    <DataGridTextColumn Width = "0.10*" ClipboardContentBinding = "{x:Null}" Header = "Remove" CanUserResize = "False" CanUserReorder = "False" Foreground = "{x:Null}" />                                                                                     
</DataGrid.Columns>                                                                  
</DataGrid>
```

and here is c# code where i try to put data into DataGrid

```
response = await client.GetAsync("api/user/agents");
        listOfAgents = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ICollection<ApplicationUserModel>>();                        
        dataGridAddedAgents.ItemsSource = listOfAgents;
```

I have check with debugger and i load data correctly into listOfAgents. When i run program DataGrid shows correct number of rows but all cells are empty.

edit:

```
 public class ApplicationUserModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string GuestIdentification { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Class ApplicationUserModel looks like this. i use it too write into database and it works
Soulutin:

removing Foreground = "{x:Null}" from columns in DataGrid fixed it. thanks @mm8 for the help

Comment: You're assigning the ItemsSource both in your code and via `ItemsSource = "{Binding}"` in your XAML. This is probably the cause of the problem. Remove the binding and see if it works.

Comment: Or just set the ItemsSource binding properly in the xaml

Comment: @TheLethalCoder - I did think of suggesting that, but then there might be other issues that need sorting. Removing the binding (even temporarily) would show whether it was the source of the issue or not. Once you've ascertained that you can then sort out a proper fix.

Comment: you can check output window for binding errors

Comment: @ChrisF when i remove ItemsSource in XAML same thing. when i put AutoGenerateColumns data showed without problem. but i cannot use that beacuse i dont display all things i get. Problem is somewhere in Binding columns to specific data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When i run program DataGrid shows correct number of rows but all cells are empty.

Then you need to make sure that the ApplicationUserModel class contains *public properties* (and not fields) named "Id", "FirstName", "LastName", "Email" and "Username" and that these properties actaully return the expected values.

Each property should at least have a public setter for you to be able to bind to them:

```
public class ApplicationUserModel
{
   public string Id {get; set; }
   public string FirstName {get; set; }
   ...
}
```

**Edit:** You shold also remove Foreground="{x:Null}" from your DataGridTextColumns.

By the way the ItemsSource that you set programmatically will "overwrite" the one you bind to in your XAML markup.

Comment: they are set like that  public class ApplicationUserModel
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string GuestIdentification { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Remove Foreground="{x:Null}" from your DataGridTextColumns. I updated my answer. Then it should work provided that the properties return any values.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, my variables weren't set to public, it works now.

Comment: This was similar to my issue after knocking my head against the wall for hours.  I wanted the observablecollection to refresh the UI automatically as expected, when adding a new item to the collection -- without having to do unnecessary tweaks like nulling out and re-setting the ItemSource.  Calling refresh also did not work.  It seems what I was missing was to declare my observablecollection as public.